# Batch search each folder in a directory by file extention and just keep the biggest sized file of that extention and all other file types

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have tried placing a text list inside each folder in the directory.
It is suppose to lists the file extention chosen (*.rst) , from largest to smallest
in order to delete and keep only the largest one.

```
@For /D %%I In ("c:\Temp\*")Do @(For %%J In ("%%I\*.rts")Do @Echo %%~nxJ)>"%%I\%%~nxI.txt"
```

It worked to a point but I can't get it to list from biggest to smallest
so can it be fixed or is there an easier way
to delete all but the largest *.rst file in each folder.
Thanks

Comment: `For %%J In ("%%I\*.rts")Do` returns files in the order the file system returns them. Use `for /F "delims= eol=|" %%J in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S /O:-S "%%~I\*.rts"') do` instead…

Comment: sorry @aschipfl couldn't get that to work
`for /F "delims= eol=|" %%J in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S /O:-S "%%~I*.rts"') do @Echo %%~nxJ)>"%%I\%%~nxI.txt" `

Comment: My suggested code fragment was meant to ***replace** the portion `For %%J In ("%%I\*.rts")Do`* from your question…

Comment: @aschipfl
my bad think I need new Glasses Thanks a million for your help been on this for 3 days lol

Answer (score 0):

Your code portion `For %%J In ("%%I\*.rts")Do` returns files in the order the file system returns them. Instead, use `for /F "delims= eol=|" %%J in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S /O:-S "%%~I\*.rts"') do`:

```cmd
@for /D %%I in ("C:\Temp\*") do @(for /F "delims= eol=|" %%J in ('dir /B /A:-D-H-S /O:-S "%%~I\*.rts"') do @echo(%%J) > "%%~I\%%~nxI.txt"
```

Or in a more legible style:

```cmd
@echo off
for /D %%I in ("C:\Temp\*") do (
    > "%%~I\%%~nxI.txt" (
        for /F "delims= eol=|" %%J in ('
            dir /B /A:-D-H-S /O:-S "%%~I\*.rts"
        ') do (
            rem /* There is no `~nx` modifier necessary since
            rem    `dir /B` anyway returns pure file names: */
            echo(%%J
        )
    )
)
```

The key is the [`dir` command](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) and its `/O:-S` option that sorts by size in descending order.